# Vue 3 + Vite dev server returns 404 on page reload of dynamic route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

In my project I use Vue 3.2.36 + Vite 2.9.9 + VueRouter 4.1.3
I run the dev server with `npm run dev`.
My routes definition:

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      component: () => import('@/views/About.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/user-details/:login',
      name: 'userDetails',
      component: () => import('@/views/User.vue'),
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      component: NotFound,
    }
  ],
```

When I programatically navigate with `router.push({name: 'userDetails', params: {login: 'john.smith'}})` the `userDetails` page/component is correctly displayed.
But if I browser reload dev server returns 404 and `NotFound` component is not displayed.

Chrome:
[image]

FF:
[image]

Working example: [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-router-starter-8n6fwp)
I've isolated the problem to Vite. Everything works fine with Vue CLI.
My `vite.config.js`:

```
import loadVersion from 'vite-plugin-package-version';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    server: {
      port: 8080,
    },
    plugins: [vue(), loadVersion()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
    envDir: './src/configuration',
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/_variables.scss";',
        },
      },
    },
  };
});
```

Checked my `index.html`:
`<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>`
Checked `vue-router` history mode docs and in [caveat](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#caveat) section it says that router should default to `index.html` if route is not found, and it does so with Vue CLI, but not with Vite.

Comment: ```createWebHashHistory``` works fine, but I dont want to use it. Possible solution is to use it on dev server but on production use ```createWebHistory``` with server settings explained in [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#nginx) (my case nginx) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, its know [bug](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2415) in Vite.
Solution is to use [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-rewrite-all) in Vite as stated [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2245#issuecomment-785981471)

For me, this is a no go. I'm switching to Vue CLI.
Don't want to deal with this kind of gremlins.
I'll revisit Vite in a couple of years.

Comment: it's not been couple of years, but I am 100% sure you stuck with vite ;)

Comment: The issue was closed recently, claimed as solved on `5.0.0-beta.0`

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
I use the vite + router + history mode and meet this problem in my dev env, when I first start the vite app and the router will start '/' and load my router path into '/m/xxx', and when I reload or refresh the app at this page '/m/xxx', the vite will use '/m/xxx' as root base path rather the '/'

In production:
we can use `nginx` to redirect the path to solve history mode as the old regular method.

But how do we solve the problem in development mode in the webpack there is a params `historyApiFallback` to rewrite the fallback,
but I don't find in the vite to config it, so I find a way to put the `<base href='/' />`  in my dev index.html to set the root path so that when I reload the page and it will use the '/' as base root rather to fetch the '/m/xxx/src/index.ts'.

```js
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html';

defineConfig({
      plugins:[createHtmlPlugin({
        minify: true,
        entry: 'src/index.ts',
        template: 'build/vite/index.vite.html',
        inject: isProduction ? {} : {
          tags: [
            {
              injectTo: 'head-prepend',
              tag: 'base',
              attrs: {
                href: '/'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      })
  ]
})
```

Another way, try to replace the `vite-plugin-html` with `vite-plugin-parse-html` could be better to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

My webapp is on Azure DevOps but its on Linux
For Linux webapps you have to add next command to run your Webapp on startup command. This works for me.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

You can see more in this article [React app on Azure webapp linux](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try a .htaccess file in the dist folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

[https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations][1]

As found in [https://gist.github.com/Prezens/f99fd28124b5557eb16816229391afee][2]

Comment: OP is running Vite server, not Apache.