# VueJS vite development rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, vuejs3, vite

I'm new to VueJS/Vite and trying to setup my development environment.
I set up my env on a MacBook using VS code and connect remotely through SSH to my Ubuntu server (running Apache2).

When testing my app, VS Code connects me to http://localhost:5173 and displays the app.

As I'm using Vue router, I would like to implement redirect rules to redirect all pages to my index.html page.

I read that I need to create a .htaccess file but I'm a bit confused: where should I create it? On my local MacBook environment or on my server?

Thanks a lot
Alex

Comment: You'd edit the `.htaccess` on the server, as that's what would be doing the redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where is the server when using a dev Vite environment through ssh? (tuneled http://localhost:5173/)

Comment: Actually, if you're using Vite as a dev server, the rewrites to index.html should already be happening, assuming default Vite configs. I'm confused why you need to manually do this.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for your answer. I'm using vue-router with dynamic URL. When I am in my dev environment, if I reload vue-routed url, I get 404 not found which is annoying. I solved the problem with a htaccess file in my production server but can't get it fixed with my dev server. I tried to put the .htaccess file in the src directory of my vite dev server. Am I right? Why isn't it working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Adding ".htaccess" only works for Apache server which I use in production but not for dev (it is Vite Server). I had the same problem as :
[Vue 3 + Vite dev server returns 404 on page reload of dynamic route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224786/vue-3-vite-dev-server-returns-404-on-page-reload-of-dynamic-route)

Vite is supposed to redirect to index.html but it doesn't. It is a bug you can solve by installing the following plugin in Vite:
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-rewrite-all)